# Highcharts: duplicate datalabel text on export

Tags: javascript, highcharts, png

I've come across a weird glitch with Highcharts export (to PNG, SVG etc). Essentially, when exporting, the datalabels on the chart become garbled, so that they duplicate like so:

[image: Duplicated text]

I've tried changing the export image dimensions (even to match the original div size exactly) but I still have the same issue. The only thing I can think that might be affecting it is a custom formatter function (which shows the percentage after the total for each data point), but there's no manipulation of text size or anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Provide an example that replicates the problem.

Comment: This is bug in Highcharts reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3649).

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a new problem in the export service.

I was able to work around it by disabling text shadows on the data labels. To do this, I added:

```
dataLabels: {
    style: {
        textShadow: ''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. I disabled the textShadow inside the series

```
series: [
        {
         name:'Serie1',
         data:[2027.15, 2027.15, 0.0], 
         dataLabels:{
                enabled: true, 
                style: {textShadow: 'none'
                }
        }
    ]
```